# Totaling up values in a for loop that uses callbacks (Java / Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm attempting to total up the scores in a for loop. The problem is that each call in the for loop uses a callback. The below code shows the intention but I am getting the error that totalScore and totalHealth would need to be final in order to be used. If they are final then I can't total them up. Is there no way in java to make this happen? I realize that the for loop will complete each callback at separate times. To account for this I run my own check of when (referencesAdded == totalReferences) to know when to add up al the scores and callback with the answer.

I guess the basic question is: how do I total up number values in a for loop that uses callbacks? Is it possible? And if not, how should I structure this differently?

```
public interface ScoreAndHealthCallback {
    void scoreAndHealthReceivedCallback(Map<String, Number> scoreAndHealth);
}

public void scoreAndHealthForPassage(final Passage passage, final ScoreAndHealthCallback scoreAndHealthCallback) {

    double totalScore = 0.0;
    double totalHealth = 0.0;

    int referencesAdded = 0;
    int totalReferences = passage.references.size();

    for (Reference aReference : passage.references) {

        scoreAndHealthForBaseLevelReference(aReference, new DataHelper.ScoreAndHealthCallback() {

            @Override
            public void scoreAndHealthReceivedCallback(Map<String, Number> scoreAndHealth) {

                totalScore = totalScore + (double)scoreAndHealth.get("score");
                totalHealth = totalHealth + (double)scoreAndHealth.get("health");

                referencesAdded++;

                if (referencesAdded == totalReferences) {

                    score = totalScore / counter;
                    health = totalHealth / healthPresentCounter;

                    Map<String, Number> map = new HashMap<String, Number>();
                    map.put("score", score);
                    map.put("health", health);
                    scoreAndHealthCallback.scoreAndHealthReceivedCallback(map);

                }
            };

        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't change those local variables(totalScore, ...) because they are passed to the annonymous class instance by value and not by reference. If you really need similiar  behaviour to what you did, you can wrap those local variables to local class and than use instance of it.

Look at this example i made:

```java
package so;

import java.util.Arrays;

interface Work<T> {

    void doWork(T item);

}

class CollectionUtils {

    public static <T> void each(Iterable<T> iterable, Work<T> work) {

        for (T item : iterable) {

            work.doWork(item);

        }

    }
}

public class Example {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        class Temp {

            int total = 0;

        };

        final Temp temp = new Temp();

        Integer[] values = {10, 20, 30};

        CollectionUtils.each(Arrays.asList(values), new Work<Integer>() {

            public void doWork(Integer val) {

                temp.total += val;

            }

        });

        System.out.println("Total value: " + temp.total);

    }

}
```